# How to get an affiliate reports via ebay API call?

Tags: ebay-api, affiliate

I'm would like to access my affiliate reports via API? is that possible? I've already made a search on ebay API but I didn't find request for affiliate report.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, but the functionality is not handled by the eBay Developer program. Instead, you'd request the data from eBay Partner Network. They have a loose "API" for scripting access to your Transaction Download Report.

Follow the instructions for TDR [here](https://partnernetwork.ebay.com/scripting-downloads).

For accessing web-UI reports inside the ePN portal, you might need to scrape them. I think you can at least have un+pw parameters in your login URL. You'll have to look around the ePN site at the link above and see about details like that.